# Didn't authorize WINE install correctly, now have ttf-mscorefonts-installer issues

Tags: apt, software-installation, fonts

I was trying to install WINE, and I didn't know how to correctly click OK on the licence window that came out, and I ended up 'x'ing out of it.

Now I'm stuck in the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` fault. My software centre just crashes as soon as I open it.

I keep getting

```
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I can't seem to purge it, or reinstall it.